# magento coupon code is not valid

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.0.2. For some reason, I keep getting "Coupon code "XXX" is not valid." I investigated a little bit, and found what the problem is but I don't know how to fix it.

in the file: \app\code\core\mage\checkout\controllers\cartController.php

```
$couponCode = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');
if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('remove') == 1) {
    $couponCode = '';
}
$oldCouponCode = $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode();

if (!strlen($couponCode) && !strlen($oldCouponCode)) {
    $this->_goBack();
    return;
}

try {
    $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $this->_getQuote()->setCouponCode(strlen($couponCode) ? $couponCode : '')
    ->collectTotals()
    ->save();

    if ($couponCode) {
        if ($couponCode == $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Coupon code "%s" was applied.',Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($couponCode))
                );
        }
        else {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(
            $this->__('Coupon code "%s" is not valid.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($couponCode))
                );
        }
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Coupon code was canceled.'));
    }
```

The problem is that `$this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode()` comes empty. It's coming in as ''.

Edit:

A further investigation led me to the a more specific problem..

Its the `->collectTotals()->save();` that doing all the mess..
For some reason if i remove them it runs perfectly but the coupon doesn't apply.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Check the value of $couponCode. `var_dump($couponCode);`

Comment: $couponCode is the number i entered in the form...

as you can see its being printed already in the error.

Comment: This is potentially causing your `$couponCode` to become blank: `strlen($couponCode) ? $couponCode : ''`

Comment: So what you need to do is figure out why `$couponCode` is empty prior to this check... which could be coming from: `$couponCode = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');
if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('remove') == 1) {
    $couponCode = '';
}`

Comment: I kept investigating a bit and it seems that it was a database error.
in the table `salesrule` there are 2 columns called `website_id` and `customers_group_ids` the in them was `Array` so i changed it to they right id's.

now i have a new problem every time i try to create a new cart rule the value entered in to them is `array` i don't know in what file this is being processed and inserted to the db this way.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common bug of Magento from that version while they told that this bug was fixed but it wasn't. Also at the bug tracker of Mangeto it's still showing that the issue is "In Progress" till now. Here what I have found from https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix :

Shopping Cart Price Rule Fix
When creating a shopping cart price rule in Magento CE 1.9 and using 'Stop Further Rules Processing', the logic has been changed since 1.8 CE and is now flawed. This flawed logic now stops rules being applied correctly with more than one product in the cart and doesn't consider 'Stop Further Rules Processing' at the item level. This means that you get incorrect discount amounts applied as per the bug report here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/67

This extension corrects the flawed logic and causes 'Stop Further Rules Processing' to be considered at the item level allowing rules to be processed for all items in the cart.

Comment: You might also want to mention that you're the author of that extension, else this looks like spam.